# ANDROID_HOME is not set?

Tags: android, path, environment-variables

I am currently setting up an Appium platform and it's having trouble finding my `ANDROID_HOME` path. I have the sdk downloaded and installed in `Users/User/Android/sdk`. My `bash_profile` looks like this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
export JAVA_HOME=$/usr/libexex/java_home       
export ANDROID_HOME=Users/User/Library/Android/sdk 
PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform_tools
echo $ANDROID_HOME
```

When I run Appium Doctor, I get the following error message:
`✖ ANDROID_HOME is set but does not exist on the file system at "Users/Toast/Library/Android/sdk"`

That is the path to the SDK as defined in Android Studio. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you are missing a `/` in the beginning of the absolute path for `ANDROID_HOME`. It should probably start with `/Users..`. Something like:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/User/Library/Android/sdk
```

Comment: I feel really dumb. That's it.